# app's installation process yell that I don't have enough disk space, but I do

Tags: partitioning, software-installation

I'm trying installing an app downloaded from the internet (it's quite a big site - [Altera](https://www.altera.com/), so I don't think the problem lies in the installation file). In terminal I ran

```
sudo ./install
```

and follow the instruction in the process. An error then show up and halt the process, telling me that I don't have enough disk space (it says I don't have ~ 3.5 Gb free, but I have ~ 30 Gb). It looks like this

```
------------------------------------------------------------

                         Cyclone II     12288k

------------------------------------------------------------

Total size: 12288 kbytes

Do you want to proceed with this selection (y/n): y

------------------------------------------------------------

Calculating disk space requirements...

The requested installation requires 3448620 kbytes.
/home/welcome/Downloads/quartus_free/compare: Command not found.

------------------------------------------------------------

You do not have enough disk space to install the requested items.
There are only 29993768 kbytes in /opt/altera9.1sp2/quartus.
```

Why does it yell like that and what I'm to do ??

Comment: Maybe the reason is in the "Command not found" error in the fourth last (non blank) line. I guess that the installer fails to do the space requirement compare.

Comment: Could I ask you why v9 and you haven't choose the last release v16 ?

Comment: @user.dz, no specific reason, I was learning and I would't be able to use all the features anyway. I chose v9 because it's much lighter and it matches the version installed on the PCs in my university's lab.

Comment: @NhuThaiSanhNguyen, well it seems you are installing Cyclone II libs/addon on wrong path, you should set it to the same path as quartus . try moving that downloaded package to `/opt/altera9.1sp2/quartus` then open the terminal in the same folder `/opt/altera9.1sp2/quartus` then run installation.

Comment: @user.dz ~.~ it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NhuThaiSanhNguyen, I have submited an answer, would you review it then check acceptance if it ok, otherwise please, leave a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems you are installing Cyclone II libs/addon on different path than Quartus one. You should set it to the same path as Quartus .

1. Move that Cyclone II downloaded package to `/opt/altera9.1sp2/quartus`
2. Then open the terminal in the same folder `/opt/altera9.1sp2/quartus`
3. Run the installation from there

   ```
   user@machine:/opt/altera9.1sp2/quartus$ sudo ./install
   ```